# How to update multiple objects and increment from 0 to first if filtered to last

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

How to update all existing objects of model sequentially.

For example, have object with customids 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

Delete customid  3, I then need to revalue the rest.

```
increment = 0
for obj in allobj:
    Obj.objects.filter(id=obj.id).update(customid=increment) 
    increment = increment + 1
```

and then get customids 1, 2, 3, 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming here that `customid` is not a primary key (never update primary keys like this). To adjust your objects you can use:

```
from django.db.models import F

Obj.objects.filter(customid__gt=3).update(customid=F('customid') - 1)
```

This queries for all objects whose `customid` column is greater than 3 and subtracts 1 from that column. Provided your `customid` sequence was sequential before, this update will reinstate the sequence.

This executes *one* update query, server-side.

See [*Updating multiple objects at once*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once).

Comment: Yes, perfect!, i has learning about this, and now i`m has learned this query!, thanks!.